# Create table row for every result

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT @body1 = @body1 + '<tr><td valign="top">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120) + ' </td>'
        ,@body1 = @body1 + '<td valign="top">' + ISNULL(CAST(fut.nFuturesId AS varchar), ' ') + ' </td>'
        ,@body1 = @body1 + '<td valign="top">' + 'PaperFuturesCommodity' + ' </td></tr></table>'
FROM    dbo.PositionFutures AS fut WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)
    WHERE   1=1
    --AND       fut.strUnderlying = 'V'
    AND fut.nFuturesId IN (3059, 21535)
    GROUP BY fut.nFuturesId
```

This is the part of my stored procedure that creates the table body. The result of this right now is 2 rows, but the second one is not inside the table as picture below. Why?

[image]

Comment: Could it be the `</table>` code at the end of the `select`?

Comment: Gordon might be right have a closer look at your code

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oh...I'm so stupid. Thanks a a lot! Create an answer and I will mark it

Comment: lol @krillezzz your not stupid hahaha its usually the little things that messes us up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon Linoff has it right  check your

```
     </Table>
```

at the end of the select